# How to include property file in complex project

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have a back-end project called `sample-parent` that consist of three different projects

[image: structure]

where `sample-webservice` is the one with main class. `backend.properties` file contains following information:

```
server.port = 8080
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=sample
server.servlet.context-path=/sample
```

but when I run the project, this file is just ignored, therefore I cannot connect to mongo database. From what I know, I have to mark the `backend.properties` file in `pom.xml` file, but I dont know how to do that, I was trying to find some guidelines but so far I have nothing. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: from the question it is unclear - how do you package this file into build (pom.xml's) and how do you load this file in runtime

Comment: Well, I dont load it, thats the problem, I dont know how to include `backend.properties` in main `pom.xml` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Michal, from what I see your problem is that you are trying to load the properties' values where they are not needed. In general you better put properties file to every project, but define only the values the project really cares about - here your webservice application doesn't care about the MongoDB (or shouldn't care) connection, so you better place the connection into MongoDB and remove these values from Webservice.

Anyway, if you need to centralize the properties I will highly recommend you to use properties file outside the JAR/WAR, especially if there are sensitive information like passwords, api keys, connections. In order to do that you can use configuration like this Bean (only for demonstration, not for production):

```
public PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
properties.setLocation(new FileSystemResource("/path/to/app-production.properties"));
properties.setIgnoreResourceNotFound(false);
return properties;}
```

Also you can refer to the Spring documentation regarding the **priority** of loading the properties from different sources:
[externalizing props](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config)

Answer (score 1):

Put that file into `src/main/resources` of a subproject, that needs to connect to the MongoDB.

Answer (score -3):

Specify the resource directory in pom.xml like this.

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            <targetPath>${project.build.outputDirectory}</targetPath>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
   </resources>
</build>
```

Comment: there is no need to re-declare defaults or use filtering, where it is not needed or not used